# Showing progress of xhr made by webworkers

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, web-worker

I want to upload multiple files to server using AJAX by web-workers and want to show progress to user. I know web-workers can not access UI elements. Is there work around to do that? Or any other solution without using web-worker.

Answer (score 1):

If web-workers isn't important for you, i will recommend you to take a look at this [library](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

Examples is avalible here: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

I see that you're not mention jQuery - but personally i prefer to work with that library.

Comment: I want to upload whole folder hierarchy. I don't think this library can do that.

Comment: That's a good point - but it's pretty hard to give you the right answer, when some of the most important facts is missing :-) Hope you will find another solution!